# Is there a way to solve a system of 4 equations,3 variables and 2 of the equations being nonlinear?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, python

In the problem that i am trying to solve i have 4 equations(2 linear and 2 polynomials of second degree) with 3 variables(assume it is `a`,`b`,`g`). I want to solve the two variables depending on the third e.g `a=f(g)`,`b=w(g)`. What i have tried until now is using the sympy.solve to find a solution but it only takes as argument only the 2 out of the 4 equations and if i try to use more of them as input it returns an empty list.Is there any software that i can take the result that i want( `a=f(g)` and `b=w(g)`) based on all 4 equations and not just the 2 of them?

EDIT:Added the equations

`eq1`:$(0.55+(b*(1-c)- a* c)* g+N*(\frac{-a}{2} * (1-c)^2+\frac{b}{2}*c^2))-0.8=0$

`eq2`:$0.55+(b* d-a*(1-d))*g+N *(\frac{b}{2}*(1-d)^2-\frac{a}{2}*d^2)-0.3=0$

`eq3`:
$g^2*[b^2*(1-c)+a^2*c-[b*(1-c)-a*c]^2]+N^2*[\frac{a^2}{4}*(1-c)^2+\frac{b^2}{4}*c^2-[\frac{b}{2}*c^2-\frac{a}{2}*(1-c)^2]^2]-0.008=0$

`eq4`:$g^2*[b^2*d+a^2*(1-d)-[b*d-a*(1-d)]^2]+N^2*[\frac{b^2}{4}*d+\frac{a^2}{4}*(1-d)-[\frac{b}{2}*(1-d)^2-\frac{a}{2}*d^2]^2]-0.008=0$

where c,d,N are constants.

Comment: Can you post the equations ?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yes,i corrected it in my last edit.

Comment: @Sukhoi234 just added them.

Comment: The system is overdetermined. The first two equations are a linear system that can be solved for $a,b$ in terms of $g$, then the last two equations become equations in $g$ alone. If they have a common root then that's a solution, otherwise there is no solution.